# Codeigniter pagination create this prev and next links

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I try to create pagination in CI

i have HTML

```
<!--div class="pagination">
<a href="#" class="page-prev">previous</a>
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="page-next">next</a>
```

in my controller i try this

```
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '';
        $config['prev_link'] = '<';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '';
```

how i can put prev_link and next_link outside ul ? if my full tag open must be (if i`m not wrong) with tag ul

Comment: why you need to do this

Comment: i need create pagination on page. it is logical :)

Comment: hmmm good i appreciate and yes it is logical i do accept this

Comment: i just want create links with this HTML format :)

Comment: Comment out all the tags and see what the resultant output than try to dynamically add classes to them by using selector with jquery its a long process to go along with you have to play with logics

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.pagination ul > a:last-child" ).addClass('page-next');
$("div.pagination ul > a:first-child" ).addClass('page-prev');
```

It helped me